# Like and Support Buttons for Sharepoint Items in PowerApps

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

So, essentially I have a Sharepoint list full of different items, what I want to do is provide a PowerApps plug-in with like and support buttons. When a user then hits the like button against a selected list item I want to check if they have already liked that item, if they have, do nothing, if they haven't then I want the like button to add 1 to it's current count. To make things a bit more complicated I don't want the users to actually have editable access to this SharePoint list (It would be ideal if I could just give them editable access to the likes column but SharePoint seems to only allow/deny editable access at the list level?). I am relatively new to PowerApps and as such any help anyone can provide would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,

Owen

I have had a look on StackOverflow for a while now and have tried a few different solutions for like buttons but I haven't been able to find one related to SharePoint lists meeting the same checking requirements above.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you want to create a counter.

Refer in PowerApps Forum.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Discussion/Add-a-counter-to-a-column-with-a-button-function-in-PowerApps/m-p/53600#M22258

Other is check if they have already liked that item:
Using Microsoft Flow to handle logic of this. I think you also have license of MS Flow

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think this solution is nearly what I'm looking for, the only issue is that it has set the list item that we want to update statically (in this case the item for which the subject = TED), whereas I would like for this to take place dynamically on the selected list item irrespective of which list item is selected if this would be possible?

Comment: @OwenMcGowan : I think you can add a Flow ( creating in MS Flow) which handles  selected event into each item of list. Then return return as update counted likes or remain counting number if it was liked already. 
Refer: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/return-data-to-powerapps/

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an older thread, I think this is what you're looking for.
SharePoint has an inbuilt feature to enable likes/rating on a list or document library.

Please check out the following link. 
https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-rate-and-like-items-and-documents-in-sharepoint/